# Bash script to execute commands on system boot up

Tags: linux, bash, alias

I am trying to make a bash script to check for two data values and weather or not they are set to 1 or 0 I want to do something. These values usually are set on system bootup and are defined usually after system is completely up (that is why I am using a while loop to keep checking until it is defined):

So far I have this, but I am getting an error:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s expand_aliases

alias gd126='gdget 126' # output is either 1 or 0
alias gd3='gdget 3'     # output is either 1 or 0
alias gd5='gdset 5 1'   # set this data to 1 

gd126  
gd3     


while true; do
        if [ gd126 -eq 0 ] && [ gd3 -eq 1 ]; then
                gd5; break;
        fi;
done
```

Here is the output when i run myScript.sh:

```
[root@server tmp]# ./myScript.sh
0
0
./myScript.sh: [: gd126: integer expression expected
./myScript.sh: [: gd126: integer expression expected
```

Could someone please tell me why? I tried changing '-eq' to '==' and it just stalls there with no output.

Comment: You have to execute the commands gd126 and gd3. In the if clause, replace gd126 with $(gd126). This will execute the command and fetch the output to compare with. In the current version it considers gd126 and gd3 strings and so throws an error saying integer expression expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no happy ending when using aliases, especially not in scripts. Use functions instead. In any case, use `"$(somecommand)"` if you want the output of a command, not not the command name itself:

```
#!/bin/bash
gd126() {
    gdget 126
}

if [ "$(gd126)" -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "It's 0"
fi
```

Comment: Does it matter if my command has spaces between them? e.g $(gdget 26).

Comment: No, you can put any valid command (or commands) inside the `"$(...)"`

Comment: So something like this would make sense?                                       while true; do
        if [ "$(tdget 126)" -eq 0 ] && [ "$(tdget 3)" -eq 1 ]; then
                "$(tdset 5 1)"; break;
        fi;
done

Comment: Yes, but the last one should be `tdset 5 1` because you want to just run the command, and not replace it with its output (PS: [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) points out things like that).